# Coding some PHP inside Flash Builder?

Tags: php, flash, ide, flash-builder

I use FB (4.6) for almost every coding need I have, but I found that there is no PHP support, is there any way to code some PHP opening a new tab just like any other .as or .mxml tab?.

(Intellisense and other useful stuff would be nice too)

Comment: exactly how could php, which runs on the server, open a tab in a client-side browser?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly, what I'd like to have is a way to write some PHP inside Flash Builder, instead of having to use another IDE/text editor. Right now Im using Noteapad++, but I'd like to keep it all inside FB, is possible. (Oh, and about your question, at the moment I'm running test locally, so, it doesnt matter if it's server or client in my case)

Answer (score 1):

flash builder is eclipse.  in "help" > "install new software..."; work with: "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/"; "add...".  select the software you want and install it just like you were on eclipse

if indigo doesn't work it's probably "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/"... and FB 4.7 will be something else too...

Comment: When I do that, I only see a "Pending..." in the software list. Do I need to add something else?

Comment: try again later?  sorry, for me if I paste the url in the "work with:" field I immediately get a list of software categories. btw, which version of FB are you using?